# Simple programming query

Tags: python

I need to do this logic without if..else construct
We have 3 values passed in Entity, Product, Type

```
def myfunc(Entity, Product, Type):
    if Type = Loan:
       return 0
    elif Entity == 'ML', and Product in list ['BML', 'DDML']:
       return 1
    return None
```

basically if Type is loan return 0, 
if Entity = ML and Product = BML or DDML return 1
for all other scenarios return None
Return None as a fall thru result

Comment: Why can't you use an if statement?

Answer (score 3):

```
return int(Type != Loan and Entity == 'ML' and Product in ['BML','DDML']`)
```

The logical operations return a boolean, which then can be converted to either a 1 or 0 depending if the boolean evaluation is True or False.

Comment: Apologies, the fall thru is result None. see updated snipet

Comment: In that case you'll need an if statement. You don't need "else", but you can't return an int under one condition and None under another without conditional logic in the program.